# How to binding List<image> to xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How can I to bind the images with 300x300 width and height of `images[1]` to xaml?

```
     public class TrackSpotify
    {
        public class ExternalUrls
        {
            public string spotify { get; set; }
        }

    public class Image
    {
        public int height { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public int width { get; set; }
    }

    public class Item
    {
        public string album_type { get; set; }
        public List<string> available_markets { get; set; }
        public ExternalUrls external_urls { get; set; }
        public string href { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public List<Image> images { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
        public string uri { get; set; }
    }

    public class Albums
    {
        public string href { get; set; }
        public List<Item> items { get; set; }
        public int limit { get; set; }
        public string next { get; set; }
        public int offset { get; set; }
        public object previous { get; set; }
        public int total { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Albums albums { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
 "images" : [ {
         "height" : 640,
         "url" : "i.scdn.co/image/8642802d13a53541e313781c34521a0d33099aac",
         "width" : 640
       }, {
         "height" : 300,
         "url" : "..................",
         "width" : 300
       }, {
         "height" : 64,
         "url" : "....................",
         "width" : 64
       } ],
```

```
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="200"></RowDefinition>
                                <RowDefinition Height="140"></RowDefinition>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <StackPanel  Grid.Row="0">
                                <Image Source="{Binding url}"></Image>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <Grid Grid.Row="1">                                   

                                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" Foreground="#D4D4D4" FontSize="12"></TextBlock>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding album_type}" Foreground="#404040" FontSize="15" FontWeight="SemiBold"></TextBlock>

                                    </StackPanel>


                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
```

```
var arrays = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NewReleaseSpotify.RootObject>(query);
            spotifyItems.ItemsSource = arrays.albums.items;
```

Comment: Where is `spotifyItems` declared? (Used in last line of code) You could try to use an `ItemsControl` for displaying the list of images

Comment: What problem are you having? It's a little bit hard to tell from your single sentence.

Comment: each `Item` in `arrays.albums.items` may have multiple images (`List<Image>`), so you may want to replace single `Image` control your XAML with `ListBox` or something. Anyway, to get you started, try to display only the first image : `<Image Source="{Binding images[0].url}">`

Answer (score 0):

I understand that   is not being real because you get a list instead of receiving a single image, what you can do is create a converter bind the list of images or the class and return the image you want. Try first returning the string and if it does not work (depending on the platform) try return a new BitmapImage with the url you want.

and you can set the size in the BitmapImage (it makes the processing faster) and apart set the size in the  too.

Comment: I use Json so I dont know to binding by list